# Get all accounts MCC adwords api

Tags: python

I have been looking for a few days on google but I find nothing.

I would like to retrieve all accounts manager from an adwords account.

For the moment I only get the first one.

I have seen : https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/python/account-management

I have seen :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/adwords-api/list$20mcc;context-place=topicsearchin/adwords-api/many$20mcc/adwords-api/K4Dixome8fw/adwords-api/DgWMYzpvdF8

```
from googleads import adwords


PAGE_SIZE = 500


def DisplayAccountTree(account, accounts, links, depth=0):
  """Displays an account tree.

  Args:
    account: dict The account to display.
    accounts: dict Map from customerId to account.
    links: dict Map from customerId to child links.
    depth: int Depth of the current account in the tree.
  """
  prefix = '-' * depth * 2
  print '%s%s, %s' % (prefix, account['customerId'], account['name'])
  if account['customerId'] in links:
    for child_link in links[account['customerId']]:
      child_account = accounts[child_link['clientCustomerId']]
      DisplayAccountTree(child_account, accounts, links, depth + 1)


def main(client):
  # Initialize appropriate service.
  managed_customer_service = client.GetService(
      'ManagedCustomerService', version='v201708')

  # Construct selector to get all accounts.
  offset = 0
  selector = {
      'fields': ['CustomerId', 'Name'],
      'paging': {
          'startIndex': str(offset),
          'numberResults': str(PAGE_SIZE)
      }
  }
  more_pages = True
  accounts = {}
  child_links = {}
  parent_links = {}
  root_account = None

  while more_pages:
    # Get serviced account graph.
    page = managed_customer_service.get(selector)
    if 'entries' in page and page['entries']:
      # Create map from customerId to parent and child links.
      if 'links' in page:
        for link in page['links']:
          if link['managerCustomerId'] not in child_links:
            child_links[link['managerCustomerId']] = []
          child_links[link['managerCustomerId']].append(link)
          if link['clientCustomerId'] not in parent_links:
            parent_links[link['clientCustomerId']] = []
          parent_links[link['clientCustomerId']].append(link)
      # Map from customerID to account.
      for account in page['entries']:
        accounts[account['customerId']] = account
    offset += PAGE_SIZE
    selector['paging']['startIndex'] = str(offset)
    more_pages = offset < int(page['totalNumEntries'])

  # Find the root account.
  for customer_id in accounts:
    if customer_id not in parent_links:
      root_account = accounts[customer_id]

  # Display account tree.
  if root_account:
    print 'CustomerId, Name'
    DisplayAccountTree(root_account, accounts, child_links, 0)
  else:
    print 'Unable to determine a root account'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Initialize client object.
  adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()
  main(adwords_client)
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: I use "Get the account hierarchy under the current account"

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/python/account-management

Comment: It's work for me :

If you are looking to get all accounts that are directly accessible authenticated user, you can use CustomerService.getCustomers() without specifying the clientCustomerId in the request. 

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201708/CustomerService#getcustomers

Comment: But how do you know which are MCC accounts that have sub accounts?